# Reference two php files at once

Tags: php, javascript

I noticed that on facebook, when you click on an image it opens up in their photo viewer. I understand that is done with javascript, but when you look at the url it says:

http://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=3230830261587&set=a.1664092454121.85323.1591534315&type=1&theater

But, you can still see your profile/or news feed (wherever you were when you clicked on the image) behind the photo viewer. How? It appears (upon observation of the url) that you have been redirected to facebook.com/photo.php. Is that the case? And how are you redirected back to www.facebook.com/(previous).php when you close the viewer?

Comment: No. The URL is modified with JavaScript using new features introduced with HTML5's history API. The image overlay is done with JavaScript too; the page never reloads.

Answer (score 3):

Facebook uses a new browser feature that can modify the browser's history. See http://badassjs.com/post/840846392/location-hash-is-dead-long-live-html5-pushstate for how Facebook changes the URL in the address bar. To display the photo, all that Facebook does is show a DIV over the document body at the same time.